# Problems with creating and using of delegate-protocols

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have the problem that I have created a delegate protocol, but the necessary methods are not executed, although I have implemented the protocol in my header file. Here are the detailed explanation:

I created an instance of my ViewController (TimeLineViewController), which will be displayed. This ViewController contains a UITableView, which in turn receives the individual Cells / Rows from one instance of my TableViewCell. So the ViewController creates an instance of TableCellView.
The TableViewCell contains a UITextView, which contains web links. Now I want, that not safari opens the links, but my own built-in browser. Unfortunately TableViewCell can not open a new ViewController with a WebView, so I decided to create a delegate protocol.

The whole thing looks like this:

WebViewTableCellDelegate.h:

```
@protocol WebViewTableCellDelegate
-(void)loadWeb;
@end
```

Then I created a instance WebViewDelegate in the TableViewCell:

```
  id <WebViewTableCellDelegate> _delegate;
```

In the .m of the TableViewCell:

```
 @interface UITextView (Override)
    @end

    @class WebView, WebFrame;
    @protocol WebPolicyDecisionListener;

    @implementation UITextView (Override)

    - (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id < WebPolicyDecisionListener >)listener
    {   NSLog(@"request: %@", request);
        [_delegate loadWeb];
    }
    @end
- (void)setDelegate:(id <WebViewTableCellDelegate>)delegate{
    _delegate = delegate;}
```

And in my TimeLineViewController I implemented the protocol with <> and the loadWeb-metode:

```
- (void)loadWeb{
    WebViewController *web = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    web.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController: web animated:YES];
    [web release];
}
```

And when the instance of the TableViewCell will be created in the TimelineViewController:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    MyIdentifier = @"tableCell";
    TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = tableCell;}

    [cell setDelegate:self];
//…
}
```

It is the first time I created a own delegate-protocol, so maybe there are stupid mistakes. Also I´m learnung Objective-C and programming generally only for 4 weeks.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I think i found the problem, but I dont know how to resolve it. I try to use `[_delegate loadWeb]`; in the subclass of the UITextView (because that is the only way i can react on the weblinks) and the subclass can´t use `[_delegate loadWeb];`. I tried this in a other methode and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that:

```
id <WebViewTableCellDelegate> *_delegate;
```

should be:

```
id <WebViewTableCellDelegate> _delegate;
```

The `id` type is already a pointer reference to an instance.